# SSAS - Data Warehouse structure and the Unknown value

Tags: excel, ssas, business-intelligence, olap-cube

I have a table that shows summed monthly values grouped by different analysis codes

```
TableId    Month    Value    Analysis1ID    Analysis2ID
1             1      100         1             NULL
2             1       50        NULL            3
3             1       50         2             NULL
4             1       50         3             NULL
```

I have set the above as a fact table (also have a dimension for the analysis values).
As you can see the table has a new row for each unique ID for the analysis column.

We are then analysing the data in excel, Simply summing the Value column and grouping by Analyis1ID, Month

This give us :

```
AnalysisID1 1 = 100 
AnalysisID1 2 = 50 
AnalysisID1 3 = 50 
Unknown       = 50 
Total = 250
```

This all looks ok apart from the Unknown, which is summed total of NULL....

I have tried excluding the NULL Value in the Dimension by setting the UnknownMember to "Hidden".

This does work but it does not exclude the amount from the total. How can i exclude it from the total value?

I am guessing that the table structure is not correct for that data, I'm unsure though how else to structure it?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated

Comment: What exactly do you want to do and what result do you want from the above input data?

Comment: I want to show the values grouped by Month, Analysis Value\ID... So if i group by Analysis1ID, i want to see the break down for each of the contained ids i.e. 1 = 100, 2 = 50, 3 = 50. Then AnalysisID2, which i would see just 3 = 50.

Comment: That part was fairly clear in the question. What do you want to do with the **NULL** and **Unknown** values? What exactly do you want the output to be, show an example, make it clear how the **NULL**, **Unknown** and **Total** values should be displayed or not displayed.

Comment: Apologies.... I don't want the NULL values displayed. I don't want them to add into the group total either.

Answer (score 1):

I would not have NULL values in dimension members, in the past i've always used an Unallocated Member with a -1 ID.

You could then use Cube Security to filter out the Unknown or Unallocated members.

Answer (score 0):

I would Filter that row out using Excel.  Right-click on the cell labelled 'Unknown' and you can choose Filter / Hide Selected Items.